# TextField not showing placeholder text when cleared programmatically. is there a way to remove this behavior?

Tags: swiftui

I have the following code. When I clear the `TextField` binding property on the view model, the placeholder text isn't shown again until the `TextField` becomes first responder again.
[image: Demo Gif]

```
struct SomeView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TextField("Enter something here..", text: $viewModel.text)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                .disableAutocorrection(true)
            Spacer()
            Button("Reset") { self.viewModel.reset() }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var text = ""

    func reset() {
        text = ""
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be an intermittent bug. In my limited testing it seems to be resolved with iOS 14 / Xcode 12. Have you found any fix or workaround for now?